# @Filter on two entities in one QueryDSL query result in one whereclause

Tags: java, hibernate, querydsl

I have multiple entitys that need to be uniformly filtered by one Row. To keep it simple, i want to use @Filter on each instead of changing every query involved.
Now when i activate two @Filters, only one (the one in the from entity) is applied, the @Filter of the joined entity is ignored without error message.
Minimal example:
Entity A:

```
@Entity 
@FilterDef(name="ExampleFilterA", parameters=@ParamDef( name = "version", type = "integer" ) )  
@Filters( {
@Filter(name="ExampleFilterA", condition=":version = MY_VERSION") } )
@Table(name = "TABLE_A")

public class EntityA implements Serializable {
private Integer myVersion;

@Column(name = "MY_VERSION")
public Integer getMyVersion() {
    return myVersion;
}
public void setMyVersion(Integer myVersion) {
    this.myVersion = myVersion;
}

...other columns...
```

}

EntityB is similar

Loading method:

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
Session session = em.unwrap(org.hibernate.Session.class);

Filter filterA = session.enableFilter("ExampleFilterA");
filterA.setParameter( "version", 1 );

Filter filterB = session.enableFilter("ExampleFilterB");
filterB.setParameter( "version", 1 );

JPAQuery exampleQuery = query()
    .from(A)
    .join(A.entityB, B);
```

Now this generates a query (taken from server log) that has only a `WHERE ? = TABLE_A.MY_VERSION`, no where for TABLE_B. Result: expected Data plus wrong version entrys from table B.

Answer (score 0):

Actually solved it myself: The collection od EntityB's JoinColumns were broken.
With correct joinColumns, no Filter is needed.